# Can I discard a card in Sequence when I have a second similar one but only one empty space on the board?

Tags: sequence

If I have two A♥ in my hand and only one A♥ is empty on the sequence board, can I discard the second A♥ since there is no empty space for it?

Answer (score 3):

No.  A card is not dead until both of it's spaces are covered by chips.

> Dead Card
>
> If you hold a card in your hand which does not have an open space on
> the game board because both spaces representing that card are covered
> by a marker chip, you are holding a DEAD CARD and you may turn it in
> for a new card. When it is your turn, place the dead card on your
> discard pile, announce that you are turning in a Dead Card and take a
> replacement card (one card per turn). You then proceed to play your
> normal turn.

According to the rules:
https://www.jaxgames.com/sequence-game-rules/